# error reading data from FastCGI server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I get the following error:

[Fri Dec 22 19:45:04.824183 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11484:tid 140643225478912] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://8-bit.nl/ag-admin/import.php?action=node
[Fri Dec 22 19:45:04.824289 2017] [core:error] [pid 11484:tid 140643225478912] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] End of script output before headers: getSpecificNode.php, referer: http://8-bit.nl/ag-admin/import.php?action=node

It's a PHP-script which reads XML files and post this into the database.

I found online that it has something to do with **FcgidBusyTimeout**. How can I change this value in .htaccess? I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: Possibly setting FcgidBusyTimeout in your web server config to something higher maybe?

Comment: As is [written in Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidbusytimeout), it is not possible to set `FcgidBusyTimeout` in *.htaccess* file; if that indeed is the culprit.